# some faces not showing material correctly

Tags: texturing, uv

I have this simple star mesh where 2 faces don't show the texture correctly.  I've unwrapped the UV, deleted the faces and remade them, and made sure the face orientation is correct.
[image: The circled area is the faces that aren't showing the texture correctly]

Comment: hello could you please pack your image and share your object?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/t/H5E9kkTTmhg9Oy6m zipped the blend file and image.

Comment: Hi! The textures are missing from the blend file, could you please pack your textures and re-upload. File > External Data > Pack Resources, then save.

Comment: Sorry, those were just some old links, all the textures actually used are procedural. I did remove the unused textures and then packed the external data here. https://www.dropbox.com/t/H5E9kkTTmhg9Oy6m

Comment: it just looks like a lighting problem, if you rotate the object it will display the texture as it should

Comment: Thanks, weird I thought I had tried moving lights.

Comment: The rest of the star has been assigned the material Gingerbread but these 2 problematic faces have been assigned the material Gingerbread.001. The difference between the 2 materials is that the Gingerbread material is connected to the Texture Coordinate > Object socket and the Voronoi Texture > Scale is set to 5.00, the Gingerbread.001 materials is connected to the UV socket and the Voronoi Texture scale is 30.50 !  To fix, assign the 2 faces the same material as the rest of the star (or set the Voronoi scale value to 5.00).